# Why does Mac OS X move process memory to swap even though RAM is available?

Tags: macos, memory, 64-bit, osx-lion

I'm using a Mac with 8 GB RAM running Mac OS X 10.7.2. I wrote this small program to allocate about 6GB of RAM:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<char> vec;
    vec.resize(6442450944);
    std::cerr << "finished memory allocation\n";
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
}
```

When i run the program, at some point the program does not get real memory anymore, but swap space is allocated instead. Even content already written to the RAM is moved to SWAP. When I run

```
./memtest & FOO=$! && while true; do ps -orss -p $FOO | tail -n1; sleep 0.2s; done
```

I get the following output:

```
     4
524296
1052740
1574188
2024272
2493552
2988396
3481148
3981252
4484076
4980016
5420580 <= from here on, RSS goes down
5407772
5301416
5211060
5163212
5118716
5081816
5039548
4981152
4897772
4822260
4771412
4715036
4666308
4598596
4542028
4521976
4479732
4399104
4312240
4225252
finished memory allocation
```

When I start a second process, even more memory of the first process is moved from RAM to SWAP. Is there any way to control this behaviour and make Mac OS X use the available RAM?

Comment: You can always completely disable swapping. This will also improve performance, and it shouldn't effect anything since you do have 8gb of ram. http://osxdaily.com/2010/10/08/mac-virtual-memory-swap/

Comment: The job of an operating system is to ensure that *one* process doesn't consume all of the system resources.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah, so what are the exact details concerning mac os x here? there a no limits set with ulimit, so there must be another mechanism. and why is the RAM used at first, if its a restriction? and anyway, as i stated above - the effect is not limited to a single process - launching another process, even as another user, pulls down the first processes RSS